# How to get the statistics of Hibernate Lucene Index creation in GUI?

Tags: indexing, orm, lucene, hibernate-search

I developed an admin panel for showing the Hibernate Lucene Index Statistics while creating the `MassIndexer` when my application in maintenance mode.I found in documentation that we can get the statistics by using `SearchFactory.getStatistics()` but I am not getting any statistical info, below is my snippet

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        boolean flag=false;
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        SearchFactory searchFactory = Search.getFullTextSession(session).getSearchFactory();
fullTextSession
             .createIndexer(ABC.class)
             .typesToIndexInParallel( 2 )
             .batchSizeToLoadObjects( 25 )
             .cacheMode( CacheMode.IGNORE )
             .threadsToLoadObjects( 5 )
             .idFetchSize( 150 )
             .progressMonitor(new SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor()) //a MassIndexerProgressMonitor implementation
             .startAndWait();
            Statistics statistics2 = searchFactory.getStatistics();
            session.clear();
```

I referred in the following link that we can provide the GUI for the index creation[[Can we create Lucene indexes only once at for initial set up only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645567/can-we-create-lucene-indexes-only-once-at-for-initial-set-up-only][1])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Statistics` object collects statistics about the normal usage of Hibernate Search.

To collect data about the Mass Indexer progress, you should plug in your own `org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.MassIndexerProgressMonitor`.

The `MassIndexerProgressMonitor` is an interface so you can either implement your own, or extend the `SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor` and override some methods if you prefer.

```
MassIndexerProgressMonitor monitor = new CustomIndexerProgressMonitor();
fullTextSession.createIndexer(ABC.class)
            .progressMonitor(monitor)
            .start();
// Now your custom index progress monitor will receive notifications about the progress
```

By collecting the data on your custom `MassIndexerProgressMonitor` implementation you can implement a progress bar or something similar.

- You know already which types it's going to index: the ones you have told him to (in the example above, all objects of class `ABC` and its subclasses.
- The method `MassIndexerProgressMonitor.addToTotalCount(long)` will be invoked multiple times - technically for each sub-type - but all invocations happen "at the beginning" of the process so you can use this as an estimate of the total number of elements to be indexed (your "100%").
- The method `MassIndexerProgressMonitor.documentsBuilt(int)` will let you know about progress being made: this will be invoked many times, you have to keep a total counter in your implementation to keep track of the total progress - from here you can estimate how far you've come.
- You can combine these metrics with some time tracking to **estimate**  how long it will take to complete.

Remember indexing is a bit faster when the index is small and fits in your ram, so it tends to slow down a bit while progressing. People are normally annoyed if you give an optimistic estimate and then slow down, while they are happy if you over-estimate slightly and then actually perform slightly better, so you might want to adjust the calculation for the estimated time to be slightly pessimistic - how much will depend on your typical index size and disk speed, so try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sanne it is working fine but, we would like to show the entire indexing logs in the admin GUI like 
1.which entities get indexed?
2.howmany rows get indexed for a particular entity?
3.Can we pre-estimate the time to create the whole entities ? , becuase we would like to show the Progress Bar to the user like how we show while uploading a file

Comment: You are given all the information via the `MassIndexerProgressMonitor` API. I've amended the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sanne your answer is pretty good for progressing bar but here, "how do we get which entity is getting processed"? because `MassIndexerProgressMonitor.addToTotalCount(long)` is not giving the total count of all entities at a time but giving them one by one which is a bit difficult to me to set up my progress bar to 100% when there are multiple entities in my `MassIndexer` query.So, I decided to show the progress bar by the one after other entity using the above metrics

Comment: have a look on this MassIndexer                  
MassIndexerProgressMonitor monitor = new CustomIndexerProgressMonitor();
fullTextSession.createIndexer(**ABC.class,DEF.class,XYZ.class**)
            .progressMonitor(monitor)
            .start();

Comment: @Sanne.In my application I implemented an admin panel for index creation.` fullTextSession.createIndexer(ABC.class,DEF.class,XYZ.class)` .I Observed from this `addToTotalCount(long count)` some times I am getting total count of  **3 entities(ABC,DEF,XYZ)**,and some times I am not getting count of **3 entities(ABC,DEC,XYZ)** instead I'm getting any one of them's count.So If I am restarting my index creation again I'm getting 3 entities count.Why it is showing different behaviour for each execution.